# calculate the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}(3 +\frac{1}{n})^{n}(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{n})^{2n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I have tried to calculate this limit  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(3 +\frac{1}{n})^{n}(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{n})^{2n}$$ by using the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + 1/n)^n=e$

But I just can't find how to shape the limit in such a way so that I can use that fact. Can somebody help with this one and explain too?

Comment: Are you aware of  $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + x/n)^n=e^x$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Probably take the log and use it's properties.

Comment: More interesting would be to ask for the limit of $$\left(3 +\frac1n\right)^n\left(\frac13+\frac1n\right)^n$$ Are you sure this is not the text of your exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(3+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty}3^n\left(1+\frac{1/3}{n}\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2n}\left(1 + \frac{3}{n}\right)^{2n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{3^n}\cdot e^{1/3} \cdot\left(1 + \frac{6}{2n}\right)^{2n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{3^n}\cdot e^{1/3} \cdot e^6\\
&=0
\end{align}

Comment: This is ok (+1), but you are missing $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ on the right hand side of the equalities.

Comment: Fair enough, it's a bad habit. I'll add that in.

Answer (score 1):

You have: $a_n = \dfrac{1}{3^n}\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^{3n}}\cdot\left(\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\frac{n}{3}}\right)^{\frac{n}{3}}\right)^{6}\to 0\cdot \sqrt[3]{e}\cdot e^6=0$ .

Answer (score 0):

We know that the number $(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{n})$ as $ n$ grows larger will go closer and closer to $\frac{1}{3}$, and $(3 + \frac{1}{n})$ will go to $3$. Hence, the product should go to $0$ as it is equivalent to $$\lim_{n \to \infty} 3^n.\frac{1}{3^{2n}} = 0$$